# Pandora password recovery

Tags: account-recovery, pandora

I set up Pandora on an iPad nearly two years ago. I now have a new Samsung Galaxy S4 that I want to install the app to, but can't remember the password for the Pandora account. How do I recover the password?

Answer (score 2):

Goto the following `URL`: [I forgot my password](http://help.pandora.com/customer/portal/articles/24665-i-forgot-my-password).

Get your password sent (or the request to file for a new one) or follow the instructions on your iPad, see screenshot:
[image]